# Remove selected option if disabled

Tags: javascript, jquery

As the title suggests, I would like to have the selected option cleared when disabled.

For instance, if a user selects "Angelina Jolie" and clicks the checkbox "Exclude Name", `Angelina Jolie` should be deselected and disabled and the select should show "Select Name" instead.

**[JSFiddle Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/c26teqjb/](https://jsfiddle.net/c26teqjb/)**

HTML

```
<div class="">
  <label class="checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox" name="optradio" id="filtri">
    <span class="checkboxtext">Exclude Name</span>
  </label>
</div>
<select id="filtrin">
  <option selected="">Select Name</option>
  <option>Kleenco</option>
  <option>James Franco</option>
  <option>Angelina Jolie</option>
  <option>Jack Black</option>
</select>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("#filtri").click(function () {
    $('#filtrin').attr("disabled", $(this).is(":checked"));
  });
});
```

Comment: Please use on-site Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button) for live examples, not off-site resources like jsFiddle; [here's how to do one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can reset to first index like below,

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("#filtri").click(function () {
    $("#filtrin").prop('selectedIndex', 0);
    $('#filtrin').attr("disabled", $(this).is(":checked"));
  });
});
```

Comment: But if you remove it from the list, that automatically goes back to "Select Name"

Answer (score 1):

check this

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("#filtri").click(function () {
    $('#filtrin').attr("disabled", $(this).is(":checked"));
    var x = $('#filtrin').val();
    $('#filtrin option').each(function(){
     console.log($(this).text());
      if($(this).text() == x && $(this).text() !="Select Name"){
       $(this).remove();
      }
     
    });   
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="">
  <label class="checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox" name="optradio" id="filtri">
    <span class="checkboxtext">Exclude Name</span>
  </label>
</div>
<select id="filtrin">
  <option selected="">Select Name</option>
  <option>Kleenco</option>
  <option>James Franco</option>
  <option>Angelina Jolie</option>
  <option>Jack Black</option>
</select>
```